# Street dice simulation - seems like code bias?

Tags: c++, dice

I have a simple console based dice game (Street craps), at this point it's essentially just a simulation.

But every time i run the code, the player seems to have the advantage.
This only gets worse over time.

Here's my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <Windows.h>

int Wins = 0, Losses = 0;

using namespace std;

class Dice
{
private:
    int NumSides;
public:
    Dice(int NumSides = 6)
    {
        this->NumSides = NumSides;
    }
    ~Dice()
    {

    }

    int Roll(int NumDice)
    {
        int Result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < NumDice; i++)
            Result += (rand() % NumSides) + 1;
        return Result;
    }

};

void PrntScore()
{
    cout << "Wins = " << Wins << " Losses = " << Losses << endl;
}


int Won()
{
    cout << "YOU WIN!" << endl;
    Wins++;
    PrntScore();
    return 0;
}

int Lost()
{
    cout << "YOU LOSE!" << endl;
    Losses++;
    PrntScore();
    return 0;
}


int main()
{

    srand(time(NULL));

    Dice D;


    while (1)
    {

        int FirstRoll = D.Roll(2);

        cout << "First Roll = " << FirstRoll << endl;

        if (FirstRoll == 7 || FirstRoll == 11) { Won(); }
        else if (FirstRoll == 2 || FirstRoll == 3 || FirstRoll == 12) { Lost(); }
        else
        {
            cout << "Point set = " << FirstRoll << endl;

            int NewRoll = 0;
            do
            {
                NewRoll = D.Roll(2);
                cout << "New Roll = " << NewRoll << endl;
                Sleep(500);
            } while (NewRoll != FirstRoll && NewRoll != 7);

            if (NewRoll == FirstRoll)
                Won();
            else
                Lost();

        }

        Sleep(500);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Is this code biased, or just extremely bad luck?

Comment: After 100 iterations, I saw more losses than wins. https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27a08cc7fabad2e7

Comment: You could try with a better `rand()` implementation, like SFMT. Your compiler's built-in `rand()` is likely garbage.

Comment: [Rand Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

Comment: What Wins and Losses numbers are you getting?

Comment: Use `::std::uniform_int_distribution` with `::std::mt19937`. Not only is `rand()` bad, also is it non-uniform to use modulo. [Example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)

Answer (score 0):

rand, srand and RAND_MAX has a great deal of issues and they are not recommended to be used. You should be considered using C++11 `<random>`.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random